# Thread issue, notification

Tags: java, thread-safety, wait, notify

I have a for loop in which a command calls a thread.

```
public void test{
    for(int i = 0 i < MAX; i++){
        callThisMethod();
// I need to put something here in order to wait until the threadX has finished
    }
}

private void callThisMethod(){
    Thread threadX = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            // do something quite time consuming
        }
    };
    threadX.start();
}
```

I am not sure how to use java.lang.Object.wait() and java.lang.Object.notify() in that situation, so the loop freezes until the threadX has finished its job.

Comment: `threadX.join()` will pause calling thread until `threadX` finishes.

Comment: Or you can try `Future` by check `futureTask.isDone()`

Comment: `wait()`, `notify()` and `notifyAll()` are synchronization constructs aswell, but they need a common synchronization object to work (i.e. the object on which `wait()`, `notify()` and `notifyAll()` is called).

Comment: @QingfeiYuan I would suggest to use `Future`s in case there is other work that can be done while the completion of the asynchronously startet tasks is awaited. If a hard synchronization is necessary, I would prefer `thread.join()`.